# What would the consequences be if there was a planet other than Earth, Venus, or Mars that was in the habitable zone?

Tags: planets, alternate-history, society

Okay, there are two habitable worlds in the Solar System. One of them is Earth. Human history goes mainly the way it really went. Then, there is another planet with a sentient, equally advanced species of humanoids on it.

---

**EDIT**
The other habitable planet would be on a separate orbital path from the Earth.

---

My questions are these:

- **Where could I put this other planet.....I considered having it in place of the asteroid belt, is this too far away. Mars has to also exist in its current location and state, as well a Venus.**
- **How might us and this species interact? Would we more likely trade or go it war over something petty?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mars as "Earth sister"](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10341/mars-as-earth-sister)

Comment: Nope, they want Mars around too.  They need to check out  [what makes a planet habitable for humans](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9944/making-a-planet-habitable-for-humanoids-the-planet)

Comment: No....in the question I think I made it clear I want the other habitable planet (let's call it Terra 2) to be separate from Mars.

Comment: Does it have to be another planet?  Given the known structure of our solar system it would be easier to wedge in a habitable moon around Jupiter or Saturn.  Alternately, would it be okay to adjust Venus, Earth and/or Mars's orbit to fit the new planet?

Comment: I am considering pushing mars farther out.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how could a habitable moon be around those gas giants. I am trying to make the world resemble Earth. Since Jupiter is so far away from the sun, chances are better that life would use thermal or radiation as energy, making the world diverge significantly from our planets habitat

Comment: Tidal pressures could generate heat enough to be Earth-like without going too hot.  Atmosphere could be similar as well.  The major difference would be in light wavelengths.  Moon dwellers would have probably evolved to see better in a shifted spectrum to us.

Comment: @MBurke Interesting idea. This would also give a (semi) justifiable reason we only recently would have discovered them. Would there be enough sunlight to grow at least some chlorophyll plants? Humans are going to visit this world and some would move there to study the aliens (and vice versa-some of them would go to Earth).

Comment: @JDSweetBeat Humans are certainly not going to visit those worlds. Jupiter puts out an astounding level of radiation as well as magnetism, if they can live in that environment there then we have nothing to talk about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would definitely be possible. It would not, however, have its own orbit.

Right now, the inner solar system is pretty full, gravitationally speaking, without much in terms of room between the inner planets for more additional planets. Your new planet, Terra II, would have to share its orbit with one of the existing planets.

**How can two planets share an orbit?**

In our solar system, most things that share an orbit with other things do so either as moons of other planets, or by hanging out in their Lagrange points, like the [Trojan asteroids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter_Trojan) do with Jupiter. You could stick an Earth-sized planet in the [L4 or L5 Lagrange points,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point) and it would be gravitationally stable.

This isn't however, the most likely way for Terra II to come to exist. While stable, the Lagrange points don't tend to be home to large bodies, probably due to the fact that the formation of a large body involves lots of energetic collisions, which are great for knocking things out of subtle gravity wells like the Lagrange points.

What's more likely is that Terra II would act as a binary partner for one of the other inner planets, such as Venus or Earth. Picture the Moon, if you will. Now picture it the size of Earth. Both planets would be large enough for an atmosphere, and the binary system would be gravitationally stable. While I don't know of any planets that have been found (so far) in such a system, we've found stars that orbit each other like this. The [Castor system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castor_(star)), for example, consists of two pairs of binary stars that orbit each other, and which are in turn all orbited by a more distant pair of binary stars. Planets could do the same.

**How would we communicate?**

Well, if both planets had intelligent life at the same time, we could do so with radio waves. We'd probably have sent a manned mission there, as well, since "We're talking to some guys on Mars and want to go say hi," is a more compelling argument than, "We want to make human footprints there, because America."

Unfortunately, intelligent life is extremely rare. It's more likely that only one planet would be inhabited by sentient creatures. We'd still have some strongly compelling reasons to go visit, but it's unlikely that we'd find anything there that resembles us.

Comment: "You could stick an Earth-sized planet in the L4 or L5 Lagrange points, and it would be gravitationally stable." No, you can not add planet sized things to lagrange points and expect stability, it changes the system entirely, it *won't even be a lagrange point* after that. Lagrange points are for significantly smaller objects, **not** planets.

Comment: Why would changing the size of the bodies perturb the system? The L4 and L5 Lagrange points represent the equilinear solutions to a circular three body problem. As such, they are maxima of effective gravitational potential for the system and will exist and be stable regardless of the sizes of any of the bodies in the system.

Comment: The third body in the [circular restricted three-body problem](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newtonhtml/node120.html) must be significantly smaller than the other two. The statement "[L4 and L5] will exist and be stable regardless of the sizes of any of the bodies in the system" is clearly wrong, except where the ratio of the masses remains the same. Just consider an extreme case, place a supermassive black hole in L4 or L5 of the Earth-Sun, do you still argue that the system will be stable? Clearly, there is a maximum size for the third body to be stable; it must be small.

Comment: It doesn't matter *how* massive the bodies are, so long as no body is inside another body's Roche limit. In an equilangular solution to a circular three body problem (not necessarily a circular *restricted* tree body problem), the resultant force on each body from the other two bodies acts through the barycenter of the system. This is true even if one of the bodies is a black hole. Why would it change? I can put the equations up here to prove it later, if you'd like.

Comment: I don't know what a *non-restricted* circular three body problem is, please describe it. I'm not saying you can not get a stable orbit out of three bodies of arbitrary mass, I'm saying you can not add an arbitrary amount of mass to the Earth-Sun lagrangian points and expect stability. [The equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point#Mathematical_details) aren't going to help you, but please add them if I'm wrong.

Comment: "because **Cold War**."  FTFY.

Answer (score 6):

The habitable zone is linked in [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9944/making-a-planet-habitable-for-humanoids-the-planet).  Also, larger than Mars (see same link) if you want humanoids.

### Short answer: it would have to be located between Earth and Mars.

Earth is on the edge of the habitable zone. [This](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2013/mar/25/earth-is-closer-to-the-edge-of-suns-habitable-zone) says Earth is on the inner edge of the habitable zone.

I don't know if it would be feasible for it to have formed there (due to gravitational constraints), it would probably have to have been a capture.

Remember, [no Counter-Earths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-Earth#Scientific_analysis).

---

### Interaction

No (large-scale) trade, nor war.   Given current tech, it's **way** too expensive to do either.  We could trade information, however.  Also, perhaps seeds or animals.  Animals might do better than plants, due to evolutionary constraints.  Possibly run ex-pat enclave, or maybe an embassy - but that would be a long-term appointment, and maybe a life-time one too.

Also, it would've changed Earth history.  Sometime around when we started 'discovering' canals on Mars, or started monkeying around with radio technology we would've had a target (and they as well).  Probably would've started a space race and or a focus for creative energies outside of warfare.

Comment: Could you link your answer to why "no Counter-Earths"?  I know there isn't one, I'm just fuzzy on why there couldn't legally be one.

Comment: @MBurke the counter-point is unstable. If you put a copy of the earth in the same orbit directly opposite of us, then one or both of earths would get pulled out of those orbits in comparably quick time.

Comment: Once again, a citation would be useful.  My understanding is that this is a Lagrange point (specifically L3), an area of inherent stability.   Also, it has not yet been stated that this has to be Earth-size.

Comment: @MBurke For placing a planet at Sun-Earth L3, please see [What are the possibilities of a dwarf planet orbiting opposite Earth's orbit?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/8651/29).

Comment: @Mburke Well, it's to have sentient humanoids on it - it *has* to be larger than Mars, and/or roughly Earth-size or larger - see habitable planet considerations.

Comment: @MBurke L1, L2 and L3 are dynamically unstable -- anything that's exactly in the right point is theoretically stable, but any slight perturbations (e.g. from the gravity of everything else in the solar system) will rapidly destroy the stability. It's only L4 and L5 that are stable, and can survive slight perturbations. That's why, for example, there are asteroid clusters in Jupiter's L4 and L5 points but not L1, L2 or L3.

Comment: "Earth is on the edge of the habitable zone" -- this is valid only for Earth-like planets, heated mainly by insolation. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4284464/ discusses planets with hydrogen atmosphere, and the habitable zone for them goes up to Jupiter orbit (and they provide a lot of possibilities for life, according to the article). Even rogue planets can keep enough internal heat under some conditions. And there is nothing fundamental preventing almost Earth sized moon orbiting Jupiter or even Saturn, heated by tidal forces and quite habitable by humans (even if a bit dim).

Comment: Given the vastly different timescales of evolution and scientific/cultural/civilization development, *trade* and *embassies* and *space races* sound very far-fetched. Either **a)** Terra_II is not home to a civilization, **b)** the civilization there is millions of years ahead of us (and for some reason did not colonize Earth, or **c)** actually created us) or **d)** that civilization is a human offshot, having gained independence some time ago and then diverged from Earth.  Two independent sentient species of about the same tech level in the same system? Quite unlikely.

Comment: @Chieron it appears you misunderstood the 'space race' comment.  In re: US vs USSR was the space race.  But the only goal was the moon, a known lifeless rock - not Terra II, a whole world to conquer.  Think the historical excitement of canal-Mars - they wanted to go colonize, plunder, mine, and enslave the (any) wogs.  Answer says, no large-scale trade (costs too much to haul bulk goods).  Trade in info/seeds is possible.  Embassies == offload troublesome political peeps you can't hang at home, but want perm. out of way.

Answer (score 1):

As a location, I would suggest that it be a larger world with Mars as its "moon".   If large enough, it would have a thicker atmosphere, so would be able to have a warmer atmosphere in spite of being on the outer edge of the goldilocks zone.

Now, to your actual question.

There would be war.   There would be trade.   There would be all manner of interactions.

Basically take any example from the age of exploration between any distant countries.   There will be similarities.  Even if significantly different from each other, it wouldn't increase the negativity too much, as humans tended to treat humans of "inferior" cultures as "non-human" anyway.

Hopefully by the time the technology progressed to allow physical contact, social progression will allow a more peaceful interactions.